# Calling REST endpoint with custom object from acceptance test

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, cucumber, acceptance-testing

I am posting a custom object from a Cucumber `Given` to an endpoint within a Rest Controller. The problem is that, as far as I've been investigating, there is no `BodyPublisher` for custom objects, and implementing one is not recommended. Therefore:

- Is it fine for the method `createMessage` to **receive a custom object** (`Message`) **or** **shall it just receive a `Map`** or a simpler structure? (Calling the endpoint with a custom object seems not natural in a native way)

**Code:**

I've got the following Given:

```
Given("^we have called the messages endpoint with a valid JSON message:$", (final DataTable dataTable) -> {
            final var messageRawData = dataTable.asLists(String.class).stream()
                    .collect(toMap(row -> row.get(0), row -> row.get(1)));
            final var faceString = messageRawData.keySet().toArray()[1].toString();
            final var body = messageRawData.get(faceString).toString();
            final var message = new Message(Face.valueOf(faceString), body);

            final var messageBodyPublisher = HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(
                    new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(messageRawData));

            final var request = newBuilder(
                    create("http://localhost:" + applicationPort + "/message"))
                    .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .POST(messageBodyPublisher).build();

            assertThat(newHttpClient().send(request, ofString()).statusCode(), is(200));
        });
    }
```

Which is actually hitting the following endpoint:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/message", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Message> createMessage(@RequestBody final Message message) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.messageService.save(message));
    }
```

Where Message is just the following POJO:

```
public class Message {

    private Face face;
    private String body;

    public Message(final Face face, final String body) {
        this.face = face;
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to achieve it (with the custom object) using the library RestAssured:

```
When("^we have called the messages endpoint with a valid JSON message:$", (final DataTable dataTable) -> {
            final Message message = assembleMessageFromDataTable(dataTable);

            response = with().body(message)
                    .when()
                    .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .request("POST", "http://localhost:" + applicationPort + "/message");
        });
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```